# How to get :id/:title with Gsub in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scaffolding

I have a `Clips Controller` where:

```
def set_clip
  @clip = Clip.find(params[:id])
end
```

My Clip has a `:title` attribute which users can set when creating.

I'm trying to achieve that in the URL the clip will be shown as:

```
http://localhost:3000/clip/1/:title
```

Plus, i need  to get gsub involved so those ugly *%20* wont show up on every Space

Can anybody enlighten me on this ?

*I'm Searching for a Solution without FriendlyID*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the /1/ is the ID of the record, having the :title as an extra in the url is redundent.

A similar (and simple) method of achieving the same result is to define `to_param` on the model:

```
def to_param
    "#{id}-{title}"
end
```

this would then give you a url in the form of "clip/1-title", which will work fine with the active record `find(param[:id])` method

Addionally, a safer param string would be to parameterize the title with:

```
"#{id}-{title.parameterize}"
```

Comment: Thanks man, "#{id}-#{title}" did the Trick, do you know how i can put gsub in to that, because on every space there is this ugly %20 sign. Thanks

Comment: I've updated the post with a 'dasherised' title string example